# Best way to export data from Java to MS Excel

Tags: java, excel

I was searching the internet for an answer to exporting data from my Java desktop app to Excel and I came across the [Apache POI API](https://poi.apache.org/). Then I found out that the JDBC would work, and then I stumbled on [JExcel](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/). Are they all equally good, or should I focus on the best among them, and which is it?

Cheers.

Comment: Please find the link here on which one to use over Apache POI and JExcel as they are good libraries for Excel documents. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763624/jexcelapi-vs-apache-poi-which-is-better)

Comment: Export exactly how much? Which format? Excel supports several formats. The easiest is using csv which is comma seperated files. This is very easy to generate. Then let excel save as a "real" excel format.

Comment: Esben, the app would allow users generate a report. That report would normally be an excel file loaded with a couple of values. How large? I'm not entirely sure, but I don't think it would be too large though. The reason I'm asking about Excel is because I want the app to take a designed template (formatted with colours, a company logo, etc), put the data in via the java app, and then open the excel file for the user to view and print. Can I go down this route with CSV?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JExcelAPI vs Apache POI, which is better?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763624/jexcelapi-vs-apache-poi-which-is-better)

Comment: I also asked about JDBC, so it can't be a duplicate

Comment: No in that case I don't think it would be a good fit for csv

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I might be late to answer this, but I guess your correct choice would be Jxls. I faced a similar scenario in my module where I had to retain a certain template like logo,color,col-span,fixed column... So that's very hectic to write a separate java code and design it.

Jxls core is poi and syntactically similar to jstl, all you need is to map a array-list of bean with desired column in excel

Answer (score 21):

Why so complicated?

Just TAB separate your columns and write the output to plain text file with an ".xls" extension?

That way, all you need to do is open the generated ".xls" file. Even though it's actually just a TAB-separated text file, Excel will open it and automatically treat each tab as a new column.

No idea why people still use csv files, frankly.

Comment: By far the best answer. Much simpler way to export.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the user gets a warning when opening a file with the extension ".xls" that is not xls.

Comment: Indeed this has caused problems for me not only with the warning, but also when the user requests any styling within the spreadsheet, e.g. zebra striping rows.

Comment: No that is not a XLS export! 
Why ? 
Well just tell me what would you do if you had to make some formulas ?

Comment: We want to export data to Excel for what Excel offers (or any other spreadsheet app) in terms of styling tables and data representations. How do you style a table with your solution?

Answer (score 0):

If the exported excel file is large, maybe there will be outofmemory exception. (It is the problem I met before, I don't know whether it is improved now.)

The most easiest way is to export as CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to do Tab separation for column and \n for row. Save as .xls.

Perfect solution :) ty Zeb

Comment: Are you sure this is a valid answer to the question?

Comment: Yea, this is not a good solution. First, problem is that MS Excel will prompt a warning saying "The file format and extension don't match. The file could be corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust its source, don't open it.". Second the OP wanted to add formatting and image, this cannot be done with that.
This requires [creating a real Excel file](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet-java/examples/create-write-excel-file-in-java/402) or writing data into a [template spreadsheet](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet-java/examples/java-export-to-excel-template/403).