# Java: Spring-MVC: Easiest Way To Export & Import Microsoft Excel?

Tags: java, spring, excel, import, export

I'm using Java 6 & Spring-MVC 3.1

What is the easiest way to export to Microsoft Excel ( .xls & .xlsx ) and import from Microsoft Excel?

Thanks

Comment: I found this [useful prior post][1] to stackoverflow


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10187218/best-way-to-export-data-from-java-to-ms-excel

Answer (score 1):

Java handles .csv files very well (which microsoft excel uses). I would convert your relevant .xls and .xlsx files to .csv files and then extend code such as the following:

http://www.roseindia.net/java/examples/io/writeToFileCsv.shtml

That should get you started. If you get stuck, a 'java read/write from .csv' search should keep you going.