# How do you export charts from websites to excel?

Tags: java, python, html, .net, r

How would one go about creating an HTML code/any code that accesses websites, exports charts that are on specific pages on these websites, and then converts those into sorted charts in excel ? If you could provide an example for different charts found on http://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2013/ ... that would be appreciated.

Comment: Use search engine to find samples. Than come to SO to as concrete question.

Comment: Python has modules for generating Excel.

Comment: Firstly use something like JSoup to extract the relevant HTML data tables. Then you need to convert this to Excel. I have a (Java) project here that will do this, with support for CSS, row/column spans, formulas: https://github.com/alanhay/html-exporter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many APIs available to perform the export, you can use

> Apache POI

for using jdbc [link for exporting to excel](http://northconcepts.com/blog/2012/12/10/export-csv-and-excel-from-java-web-apps-with-data-pipeline/)

and for more info [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10187218/best-way-to-export-data-from-java-to-ms-excel)