# How to make Excel's "Text to columns" in Java?

Tags: java, excel, hssf

I am trying to write something in Java that basically does the same thing as "Text-to-Columns" in Excel. I have a long string of data (parsed out from some HTML) and I formatted it to divide the data I need by a semicolon.

For example

```
Str = brand name;1242141;brand name;753216;brand name;2356123;brand name;656258;
```

So I want each of the brand names and numbers to be in their own cell. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java/3481842?s=1|3.9881#3481842

Answer (score 0):

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm

Str.Split(";")

Should give you the information that you would like. Getting the information into Excel is a whole other bag of cats, but

[Best way to export data from Java to MS Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10187218/best-way-to-export-data-from-java-to-ms-excel)

Is probably a great way to start.